# What happened to the King Bar in Saigon?

Tags: vietnam-war, vietnam

Bar in Saigon with playing card designs in the windows ([source](https://tsna.org/photo/feb2012/index.html)).

Considered an [important location](https://www.tsna.org/buildings/).

[image]

It was on Tu Do street, now [Dông Khoï street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Dng_%C4%90%E1%BB%93ng_Kh%E1%BB%9Fi), formerly *rue Catinat*.

Some links added in comments: [picture](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/438538082447681095/), [Saigon then and now](https://www.flickr.com/photos/13476480@N07/15587939377),
[slideshow](https://kienthuc.net.vn/kho-tri-thuc/dien-mao-doc-la-cua-quan-bar-choe-nhat-sai-gon-xua-1363720.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent picture seems to be [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nguyentichnghia/9912171103/) (from "then and now"), and it shows a "Liberty Botique" on #28, a "Playboy" store to the right, which is [apparently](https://www.tripfactory.com/places/playboy-ho-chi-minh-city-439735) #26, and a [Lynk](http://www.lynk.vn/en/home) outlet to the left, [apparently](https://dantri.com.vn/lynk-show-2016.tag) #30. The comment on the last page in the slideshow (and I believe some other page that I cannot now find) says the bar was at #30.